# Samba service won't start on 16.04 LTS (not an upgrade) anymore

Tags: 16.04, samba

HI long time listener first time caller.

I have a system running 16.04 LTS Desktop with a Samba share that has stopped starting, roughly two months ago. My attempts to restart, purge, reinstall have all failed. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Please note the most common link for my searches have been for a similar problem that presented after Ubuntu was upgraded to 16.04, which I never did. As well the solutions that involved commenting out `security = share` and `username map = smbusers` from smb.conf don't apply in my case since those were never in my `smb.conf` file.

Here is an example:

```
    user@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Calculating upgrade... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Setting up samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12) ...
    Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
    See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
    ● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-01-28 12:49:10 EST; 7ms ago
    Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 6851 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Jan 28 12:48:39 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (.....
    Jan 28 12:49:10 ubuntu smbd[6851]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
    Jan 28 12:49:10 ubuntu smbd[6851]:    ...fail!
    Jan 28 12:49:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=...=1
    Jan 28 12:49:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS d...).
    Jan 28 12:49:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Jan 28 12:49:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
    dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     samba
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I try to manually start samba, I'm told the service is masked:

```
    user@ubuntu:~$ sudo systemctl restart samba 
    Failed to restart samba.service: Unit samba.service is masked.
```

Simply unmasking doesn't help. Clearly `smbd.service` isn't starting.

I suspect I was mucking about with file permissions around that time and didn't put things back to their original state. My best guess anyway.

Really appreciate any and all suggestions.

EDITED TO ADD:

`sudo systemctl restart samba-ad-dc` gave no output, so I presume restarted without issue.

`systemctl status samba-ad-dc` output:

```
    user@ubuntu://$ systemctl status samba-ad-dc
    ● samba-ad-dc.service - LSB: start Samba daemons for the AD DC
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/samba-ad-dc; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (exited) since Sun 2018-01-28 14:25:40 EST; 16s ago
         Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Process: 4949 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/samba-ad-dc stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE
      Process: 4962 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/samba-ad-dc start (code=exited, status=0/SUC

    Jan 28 14:25:40 SVR systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba daemons for the AD DC...
    Jan 28 14:25:40 SVR systemd[1]: Started LSB: start Samba daemons for the AD DC.
```

EDIT #2:

A user alerted me to samba not working. The requested output:

```
    user@ubuntu://$ smbclient -L localhost
    WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
    Enter user’s password: 
    Connection to localhost failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
```

EDIT #3-4:

testparm output (I corrected created mask error in smb.conf to create mask and no improvement):

```
    user@ubuntu://$ testparm
    Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
    rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
    WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
    Processing section "[printers]"
    Processing section "[print$]"
    Processing section "[share]"
    Loaded services file OK.
    Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

    Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

    # Global parameters
    [global]
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        server role = standalone server
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 10000
        dns proxy = No
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        read only = No
    [printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        read only = Yes
        create mask = 0700
        printable = Yes
        browseable = No
    [print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers
        read only = Yes
    [share]
        comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
        path = /media/4TB-A
        create mask = 0755
        guest ok = Yes
```

EDIT #5a:

```
    user@ubuntu://$ sudo apt-get install -f
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Setting up samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12) ...
    Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
    ● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-01-28 15:21:41 EST; 7ms ago
         Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Process: 5967 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Jan 28 15:21:41 SVR systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
    Jan 28 15:21:41 SVR smbd[5967]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
    Jan 28 15:21:41 SVR smbd[5967]:    ...fail!
    Jan 28 15:21:41 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited...s=1
    Jan 28 15:21:41 SVR systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon ...d).
    Jan 28 15:21:41 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Jan 28 15:21:41 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
    dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     samba
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

EDIT #5b:

```
    user@ubuntu://$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
    Setting up samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12) ...
    Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
    ● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-01-28 15:22:32 EST; 7ms ago
         Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Process: 6091 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Jan 28 15:22:31 SVR systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
    Jan 28 15:22:31 SVR smbd[6091]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
    Jan 28 15:22:32 SVR smbd[6091]:    ...fail!
    Jan 28 15:22:32 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited...s=1
    Jan 28 15:22:32 SVR systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon ...d).
    Jan 28 15:22:32 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Jan 28 15:22:32 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
    dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     samba
```

EDIT #6:

I truly appreciate your time today helping me, N0rbert. I struggled with your last request over ssh but remote admin'd into the box and got it to work.

```
    user@ubuntu:/var/cache/apt/archives$ sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12_amd64.deb
    (Reading database ... 309686 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12) over (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12) ...
    Setting up samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12) ...
    Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
    ● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-01-28 16:48:22 EST; 6ms ago
         Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Process: 7175 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Jan 28 16:48:22 SVR systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (.....
    Jan 28 16:48:22 SVR smbd[7175]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
    Jan 28 16:48:22 SVR smbd[7175]:    ...fail!
    Jan 28 16:48:22 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=...=1
    Jan 28 16:48:22 SVR systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS d...).
    Jan 28 16:48:22 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Jan 28 16:48:22 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
    dpkg: error processing package samba (--install):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
    Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
    Rules updated for profile 'OpenSSH'
    Rules updated for profile 'Samba'
    Firewall reloaded
    Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
    ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
    Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21) ...
    Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     samba
```

Next:

```
    user@ubuntu:/var/cache/apt/archives$ sudo apt-get install -f
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Setting up samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12) ...
    Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
    ● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-01-28 16:51:44 EST; 5ms ago
         Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Process: 8065 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Jan 28 16:51:44 SVR systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
    Jan 28 16:51:44 SVR smbd[8065]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
    Jan 28 16:51:44 SVR smbd[8065]:    ...fail!
    Jan 28 16:51:44 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited...s=1
    Jan 28 16:51:44 SVR systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon ...d).
    Jan 28 16:51:44 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Jan 28 16:51:44 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
    dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     samba
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Next:

```
    user@ubuntu:/var/cache/apt/archives$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
    Setting up samba (2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12) ...
    Job for smbd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status smbd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    invoke-rc.d: initscript smbd, action "start" failed.
    ● smbd.service - LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/smbd; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2018-01-28 16:52:41 EST; 6ms ago
         Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Process: 8194 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/smbd start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Jan 28 16:52:41 SVR systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon (smbd)...
    Jan 28 16:52:41 SVR smbd[8194]:  * Starting SMB/CIFS daemon smbd
    Jan 28 16:52:41 SVR smbd[8194]:    ...fail!
    Jan 28 16:52:41 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Control process exited, code=exited...s=1
    Jan 28 16:52:41 SVR systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: start Samba SMB/CIFS daemon ...d).
    Jan 28 16:52:41 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Jan 28 16:52:41 SVR systemd[1]: smbd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
    dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     samba
```

I rebooted and found no improvement nor change. I changed the /etc/samba/smb.conf file as suggested with no change. And I do have permission to access the shared folder.

```
    user@ubuntu:~$ ls -ld /media/4TB-A
    drwxrwxr-x 1 user user 262144 Dec 31  1969 /media/4TB-A
```

I am really at a loss here.

EDIT #7: SOLVED!!!

User jelmer asked me to check the samba logs in `/var/log/samba`. Oddly enough, one file, `log.` in this folder was last modified early this month, with the others changed earlier. That one file indicated this:

```
    [2018/01/05 23:33:51.639673,  0] ../lib/util/util.c:285(directory_create_or_exist_strict)
     invalid permissions on directory '/var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock': has 0704 should be 0700
```

So I changed the permissions of `msg.sock` to `0700` as the message directed, and the service started when I ran `sudo apt upgrade`. Success.

Thanks to jelner for sending me deeper into the sticks, and special thanks to N0rbert for the time and patience today requesting more information, which has taught me so much more about samba and services on my system. Kudos to you both.

Comment: Please edit your question with output of `sudo systemctl restart samba-ad-dc; systemctl status samba-ad-dc`.

Comment: And how you detected that Samba does not work? What is the output of `smbclient -L localhost` (add to question)?

Comment: Let's check your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` with Samba config checker `testparm`. Please `testparm` command and add its output to the question.

Comment: Are you sure that `apt-get` completed its work successfully? What is output of `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (add to question).

Comment: Try to force all warnings with `sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.12_amd64.deb` then retry `sudo apt-get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: What do the samba log files (in /var/log/samba) say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I'll summarize all steps to fix the problem:

1. On modern Ubuntu the main Samba service is `samba-ad-dc`, user can restart them and check their status with

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart samba-ad-dc
   systemctl status samba-ad-dc
   ```
2. One can show all Samba shares with

   ```
   smbclient -L localhost
   ```
3. If no shares are shown one can check `/etc/samba/smb.conf` with

   ```
   testparm
   ```
4. To resume APT and dpkg actions one can run

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -f
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   ```
5. As we know these commands failed, so we can install Samba package forcing all warnings and then resume again:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/samba_2%3a4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04‌​.12_amd64.deb
   sudo apt-get install -f
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   ```
6. If nothing else helped try to use this `/etc/samba/smb.conf`:

   ```
   # Global parameters
   [global]
       server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
       server role = standalone server
       map to guest = Bad User
       obey pam restrictions = Yes
       pam password change = Yes
       passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
       passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
       unix password sync = Yes
       syslog = 0
       log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
       max log size = 1000
       dns proxy = No
       usershare allow guests = Yes
       panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
       idmap config * : backend = tdb


   [printers]
       comment = All Printers
       path = /var/spool/samba
       create mask = 0700
       printable = Yes
       browseable = No


   [print$]
       comment = Printer Drivers
       path = /var/lib/samba/printers


   [share]
       comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
       path = /media/4TB-A
       create mask = 0755
       guest ok = Yes
   ```

   and make sure you can access `/media/4TB-A` (check it with `ls -ld /media/4TB-A`).
7. *jelmer*'s comment about logs in `/var/log/samba` shown the following:

   ```
    [2018/01/05 23:33:51.639673,  0] ../lib/util/util.c:285(directory_create_or_exist_strict)
    invalid permissions on directory '/var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock': has 0704 should be 0700
   ```

   So the problem was completely fixed by

   ```
    sudo chmod 0700 /var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock
    sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

Comment: And what this -1 means? I hope that OP will accept my answer or suggest positive edit of my answer. While writing these I think that it would be better to have all steps in such way than read all comments and updates in question. If this is not reasonable I'll delete this answer.

Comment: Sorry, new here. I don't yet have enough rep to take away the -1, and I don't know who did that. As requested you have solved my problem. Thanks again.